# portability of htobe64 and endian.h

Tags: c

I need to put 8 bytes, that I received on an arbitrary machine that my code runs on, in to big endian order. I believe that I can use the `htobe64` function for that, but I'm not sure about the portability of that - i.e. the availability of `endian.h` - across different machines architectures and operating systems when compiling my code. Is this a safe i.e portable method to use or is it better to use a different approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use the following, portable approach:

```
#include <stdint.h>

void write64be(unsigned char out[8], uint64_t in)
{
    out[0] = in >> 56 & 0xff;
    out[1] = in >> 48 & 0xff;
    out[2] = in >> 40 & 0xff;
    out[3] = in >> 32 & 0xff;
    out[4] = in >> 24 & 0xff;
    out[5] = in >> 16 & 0xff;
    out[6] = in >>  8 & 0xff;
    out[7] = in >>  0 & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks, that solves my issue; yet, what if I need to swap different byte sequences in the future? Would I end up including several functions like this? I guess my question is essentially about the portability of `endian.h` itself.

Comment: @user4416936 `endian.h` is not portable and it's generally a bad idea to keep “endianed” numbers in numeric variables. Use a bunch of functions like the function above.